# Marking 0s and 1s on difference between images using k-means

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I have two arrays, X and Y, and I would like to use k-means to determine where the pixel has changed between image X and Y.

I could simply, make a difference between them and say: where is zero, not changed, where is greater than zero: changed. But the requirement I have is to do so using k-means.

Say, I have the following images:

```
imX = np.array([
    [154, 157, 157, 157, 150, 150, 170, 170, 175, 190],
    [154, 157, 157, 151, 153, 155, 180, 180, 170, 190],
    [154, 157, 150, 154, 160, 160, 160, 155, 155, 165],
    [157, 157, 148, 148, 148, 160, 150, 155, 155, 165],
    [100, 102, 104, 157, 142, 180, 170, 165, 10, 20],
    [100, 103, 105, 165, 155, 180, 175, 162, 40, 50],
    [100, 102, 108, 132, 180, 180, 172, 167, 25, 63],
    [18, 28, 48, 12, 13, 20, 5, 15, 30, 40],
    [15, 36, 46, 18, 21, 22, 28, 32, 30, 36],
    [17, 21, 24, 26, 35, 45, 28, 30, 40, 20]
])

imY = np.array([
    [152, 156, 157, 156, 149, 150, 170, 160, 175, 190],
    [154, 159, 157, 151, 153, 155, 180, 180, 170, 190],
    [153, 157, 155, 154, 160, 160, 160, 155, 155, 165],
    [157, 157, 148, 148, 148, 160, 150, 155, 155, 165],
    [101, 102, 104, 159, 143, 180, 170, 165, 110, 220],
    [99, 103, 105, 164, 155, 179, 175, 162, 240, 250],
    [100, 102, 108, 132, 180, 180, 172, 167, 155, 163],
    [118, 123, 148, 129, 109, 120, 155, 215, 140, 180],
    [156, 136, 210, 218, 175, 122, 128, 232, 180, 156],
    [178, 231, 245, 226, 215, 145, 188, 230, 170, 140],
])
```

> Thus using k-means to do this, I was asked to normalize the data, i.e. normalized difference between the two images:

```
diff = abs(imX-imY)
normDiff = (diff - diff.min()) / (diff.max() - diff.min())
```

Now, I have no clue how to use sklearn's k-means to mark the pixel values that **changed as 1 and 0 otherwise**, Any clue from the community?

I explored the .labels_ and .cluster_centers, when the model is fit on the normalized image difference but is not helpful. Any hints?

Comment: Why can't you subtract the two arrays, and look at all the pixels that are > 0? No k-means necessary.

Comment: ^ what @9769953 said. Also, K-means will attempt to find _clusters_ of pixels, not individual pixels

Comment: I know, it's a requirement I got asked, to use k-means. I feel stupid actually to waste time with k-means, but it's what I was asked and I have no clue.

Comment: To be honest, I'm so flabbergasted by that requirement, that I'm not sure what the best way is to help you: any k-means will be inefficient and inaccurate (as per ForceBru's comment).

Comment: You could cheat: create a True, False array mask for pixels == 0, so you only get 2 values in your entire array (no difference, any difference). Running k-means on that should show two clusters.

Comment: Note that the k-means clusters will have no bearing on the actual location of the pixels; for that, you'd really just need to subtract the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a pretty good assignment...

Any way, the idea probably is to quantize the change into two bins.nso great all the differences as a flat (n,1) data set (with n=h*w). Run k-means with k=2 to get labels. Choose the label with the larger mean as 1, the other as 0. Get the labels array and reshape it back into (w,h) to get back a 2d image. Should be pretty straightforward.